Does maximizing $\tan(\theta)$ maximize $\theta$ as well

If $v$ is the smaller velocity then $3v$ is the faster velocity. If $t$ is the time elapsed since starting from point S, then using trigonometry I found that
$$ \tan(\theta) = \frac{2vt}{1 + 3v^2 t^2} = f(t) \qquad\qquad t > 0$$
Now, question is asking for maximum value of $\theta$. Here, $\theta \in [0, \pi/2)$. So, on this domain, $\tan(\theta)$ is an increasing function. So, maximizing $\tan(\theta)$ (or $f(t)$ ) will also maximize $\theta$ as well. But how do I argue this in more rigorous manner for a Calculus problem ?

Note:
For $~0 < \theta < \pi/2, ~\tan(\theta)~$ is strictly increasing.  So, in this interval, the possible value of $~\theta~$ is maximized when $~\tan(\theta)~$ is maximized.
I am assuming that your equation
$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{2vt}{1 + 3v^2t^2} = f(t)$$
is correct.
Note that $~f(0) = 0,~$ and that $~\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 0.~$
So, it is sufficient to demonstrate that there exists exactly one (finite) value $~t_0 \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ such that

$f'(t) = 0 \iff t = t_0.$

$f(t_0) > 0.$


Assuming that this is done, then the desired computation is
$$\theta = \text{Arctan}[ ~f(t_0) ~]. \tag1 $$
So, the entire problem reduces to demonstrating the two bullet points above.
$$f'(t) = \frac{1}{(1 + 3v^2t^2)^2} \times \left\{ ~\left[ ~(1 + 3v^2t^2) \times 2v ~\right] - \left[ ~2vt(6tv^2) ~\right] ~\right\}. \tag2 $$
To find $~t_0,~$ you can ignore the denominator in (2) above, and interpret the remainder of (2) above as a quadratic equation in $~t.$
Therefore, $~t_0~$ must be positive, and must satisfy
$$t^2(6v^3) + t^2(-12v^3) + (2v) = 0 \iff t^2 = \frac{1}{3v^2}.$$
So, $~t_0~$ is uniquely determined to be
$$t_0 = \sqrt{ ~\frac{1}{3v^2} ~}.$$
It is immediate that $~f(t_0) > 0,~$ so the problem is solved by the equation in (1) above.
